# Django filtering queryset with deserialized data from session

Tags: python, django

I want to implement an object-level permission system to my Entity model in Django.
So I have a PermissionEntity model:

```
class PermissionEntity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    crud = models.ForeignKey(Crud, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Create/Read/Update/Delete
```

On my login page I store User permissions to session. Login view has the following code:

```
permission_entity = PermissionEntity.objects.filter(user_id = user.id)
permission_entity = serializers.serialize('json', permission_entity)
request.session ['permission_entity'] = permission_entity
```

And I want to get permitted entities list in my view:

```
def entity_list(request):
    permission_entity = serializers.deserialize('json', request.session ['permission_entity'])
    entity_list = Entity.objects.filter(pk__in=permission_entity.entity_id)
```

I know the current view isn't correct, but I have no idea what to do with deserialized objects in this case. Or maybe Im on the wrong way?

Comment: `pk__in` is used for list of pks i.e `[1,2,3,4]`. Does your `permission_entity.entity_id` is `list` object?

Comment: It should be a list. But I dont know how to get such list from serializers.deserialize('json', request.session ['permission_entity'])

Comment: Could you please update `Entity` Model schema to your question and what do you receive in `request.session ['permission_entity']`?

Comment: thank you for hint. I've just changed my logic: just pass the list to the session.